# How to use 'faker' libraries in karate framework?

Tags: javascript, karate

I'd like to use the 'faker' library to generate fake data in JSON file as below.

In karate-config.js, I do the following:

```
var faker = require('faker');
```

In sample.json:

```
{
    'firstName': '#(faker.name.firstName)'
    'city'     : '#(faker.address.city)'
}
```

But I'm getting error like 'unable to find 'require' keyword in 'karate-config.js'

Please help on this.

Comment: Give [this](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker) a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Karate does not support NPM or the `require` keyword. For complex custom logic, the recommendation is to use Java interop.

My suggestion is you should find a Java library that does what "faker" does and integrate it.

EDIT: for those looking for quick ways to integrate with other code, I recommend looking at the CLI option. You can call any OS process via the command-line, and if it returns data (string or JSON ideally) via the system out / err, you can capture it in Karate. So this means, if you can run a node program locally, you can use it from Karate.

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62911366/143475

Comment: thanks for your response and suggestion, tried below and working fine.

in karate-config.js:
var faker = Java.type('<package>.FakerClass');
......
config.faker = faker;


in sample.json:
> { 'name': '#(faker.address.city)' }

Comment: Are there plans for npm support in karate?

Comment: @PavelBiryukov it is not a priority for us. we use Graal as the JS engine and it technically can run Node.JS - so if the community tries to experiment, who knows :)

Answer (score 5):

First add the below dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

For the latest version of the dependency [click here](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker)

Use the below code in karate-config.js:

```
config.faker = Java.type('com.github.javafaker.Faker');
```

In the feature file use the below code:

```
* def fakerObj =  new faker()
* def fName = fakerObj.name().firstName()
* def lName = fakerObj.name().lastName()
* def mailId = fName+'.'+lName+'@test.com'
```

You could use the same in JSON body as follows:

```
"emailAddress":"#(mailId)",
"firstName":"#(fName)",
"lastName":"#(lName)",
   "address":{
          line1:"#(fakerObj.address().streetAddress())"}
```

Please [click here](http://dius.github.io/java-faker/apidocs/index.html) for the class and methods of faker package

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, karate only supports java based dependencies. So try to find a Java equivalent for your JS library.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your response and suggestion, tried below and working fine.

in karate-config.js:

> var faker = Java.type('.FakerClass');
>
> ......
>
> config.faker = faker;

in sample.json:

> { 'name': '#(faker.address.city)' }

Comment: How did you make use of faker 'npm' library inside karate project ? 
How did you manage to install faker dependency into your karate project ?