# How to execute bash script using karate and fail if script fails

Tags: java, bash, karate, intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to execute bash script using karate. I'm able to execute the script from karate-config.js and also from .feature file. I'm also able to pass the arguments to the script.
The problem is, that if the script fails (exits with something else than 0) the test execution continues and finishes as succesfull.

I found out that when the script echo-es something then i can access it as a result of the script so I could possibly echo the exit value and do assertion on it (in some re-usable feature), but this seems like a workaround rather than a valid clean solution. Is there some clean way of accessing the exit code without echo-ing it? Am I missing on something?

**script**

```
#!/bin/bash

#possible solution
#echo 3

exit 3;
```

**karate-config.js**

```
var result = karate.exec('script.sh arg1')
```

**feture file**

```
def result = karate.exec('script.sh arg1')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Great timing. We very recently did some work for CLI testing which I am sure you can use effectively. Here is a thread on Twitter: https://twitter.com/maxandersen/status/1276431309276151814

And we have just released version 0.9.6.RC4 and new we have a new `karate.fork()` option that returns an instance of `Command` on which you can call `exitCode`

Here's an example:

```
* def proc = karate.fork('script.sh arg1')
* proc.waitSync()
* match proc.exitCode == 0
```

You can get more ideas here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1191#issuecomment-650087023

Note that the argument to `karate.fork()` can take multiple forms. If you are using [`karate.exec()`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karate-exec) (which will block until the process completes) the same arguments work.

- string - full command line as seen above
- string array - e.g. `['script.sh', 'arg1']`
- json where the keys can be

  - `line` - string (OR)
  - `args` - string array
  - `env` - optional environment properties (as JSON)
  - `redirectErrorStream` - boolean, true by default which means Sys.err appears in Sys.out
  - `workingDir` - working directory
  - `useShell` - default false, auto-prepend `cmd /c` or `sh -c` depending on OS

And since `karate.fork()` is async, you need to call `waitSync()` if needed as in the example above.

Do provide feedback and we can tweak further if needed.

EDIT: here's a very advanced example that shows how to listen to the process output / log, collect the log, and conditionally exit: [`fork-listener.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/f18042b08a685d010bf3c01d8b881472ee7949de/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/core/fork-listener.feature)

Another answer which can be a useful reference: [Conditional match based on OS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69832481/143475)

And here's how to use cURL for advanced HTTP tests ! https://stackoverflow.com/a/73230200/143475

In case you need to do a lot of local file manipulation, you can use the `karate.toJavaFile()` utility so you can convert a relative path or a ["prefixed" path](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#path-prefixes) to an absolute path.

```
* def file = karate.toJavaFile('classpath:some/file.txt')
* def path = file.getPath()
```

Comment: Is there any way to suppress the stdout getting printed on console when a script is executed through karate.fork()

Comment: @AmitChouksey not directly as of now. you can try tweak the `logback-test.xml` file: https://github.com/intuit/karate#logging - anything more specific may need code changes