# Conditional match based on OS

Tags: command-line, karate

I'm attempting to use karate version 1.0.1 to test command line options.  So far, for the most part, everything is working and it is amazingly powerful and simple :)

But, I'm running into an issue.  The problem I have is that I need to test some command line scripts where the output may vary depending on OS.

Here is an example of a scenario I'm attempting to use

```
Feature: Test commands from the tool file

  Scenario: Verify contents of tool help menu options
    * if(windows) command('tool --help')
    * if(!windows) command("./tool --help")
    Then match exit == 0
    And match out contains "Usage: tool --[command]"
    And match out contains "no argument   [Run in Jetty]"
    And match out contains "--migrate     [migrate tool database using database settings]"
    And match out contains "-p xxxx       [listening port to be used (replace xxxx with a port number)]"
    And match out contains "--help        [display this message]"
    And match out contains "example: tool --migrate"

    # Some commands are OS specific
    # How to accomplish this???  What's below doesn't work
    * if(!windows) match out contains "--status      [check the status of the tool process and port]"
    * if(windows) match out contains "--install     [install tool as a windows service]"
    * if(windows) match out contains "--remove      [remove tool service]"
```

The non-OS specific commands at the top all execute and verify output as expected.  However I cannot use the if statement along with the match statement.  Is there some way to do this?

I have seen some other posts about conditional matching within if statements, but I think this scenario may be different.  I haven't yet figured out how to accomplish something like this using karate.  Unless I were to have separate feature/package for the different OS's.

Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think the API has what you are looking for, it is `karate.os`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karate-os

[image]

So this should work:

```
* if (karate.os.type == 'windows') command('tool --help')
```

You may get more ideas from the Karate Robot documentation:

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-robot#robot

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-robot#karatefork

EDIT: okay, I may have read your question in a hurry. I think the solution can be something like this, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475

So create one more helper JS function:

```
* def containsIfWindows =
"""
function(text) {
   if (!windows) {
     return;
   }
   var result = karate.match("out contains '" + text + "'");
   if (!result.pass) {
     karate.fail(result.message);
   }
}
"""
```

Then you can just do:

```
* containsIfWindows('--remove      [remove tool service]')
```

That said, since a string "contains" match is simple in JS, this may all you need:

```
* def containsIfWindows =
"""
function(text) {
   if (!out.includes(text)) {
     karate.fail(result.message);
   }
}
"""
```

Comment: The containsIfWindows js function is exactly what I needed.  Thank you

Comment: @brian glad to hear CLI testing is working. do consider blogging about it or a tweet etc. more people should know about this possibility