# Does Karate Automation allow insert a CSV file into the AWS bucket?

Tags: karate

@PeterThomas,

Can U help me?
Does Karate Automation allow insert a CSV file into the AWS bucket?

Because I need to add a CSV file into the AWS Bucket and after I need to start a Glue (ETL) process. Is it possible?

Comment: anything is possible, you just need to know how to either a) use a REST API call to do this or b) use the AWS Java SDK to do this via Karate Java interop or c) use the AWS CLI assuming it is available on the machine where Karate is running. now it is up to you to do some research and figure out what works for you

Comment: @PeterThomas do you have an example of how can I do these things that you said: ") use the AWS Java SDK to do this via Karate Java interop or c) use the AWS CLI assuming it is available on the machine where Karate is running. " Because the first option was a good idea: "use a REST API call to do this", but I don't know how.

Comment: maybe you forgot that Karate is a REST API client :) but seriously, if you know what HTTP request to send, you can make Karate do it. does that make sense ? sorry I can't help you with the exact request because I don't know AWS internals. which is why I said you need to do some research. for CLI - see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62911366/143475