# How to get a particular value when using karate.fork?

Tags: api, testing, automated-tests, karate

When we use karate.fork for CLI command and need some information from there to be stored in a variable and using it in the next step.

for EX - karate.fork('java -version')

We need to get only the version data alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then `karate.fork()` is the wrong choice - just use [`karate.exec()`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karate-exec) instead. It does the same thing, but will block, and also return the console output:

```
* def output = karate.exec('java -version')
```

Please read this also for advanced examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62911366/143475