# Escaping karate.fork Commands

Tags: karate

I am trying to run the following command in karate using `karate.fork`

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@myjumphost" -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no root@finaldest echo test
```

I have broken this up into an array to pass to `karate.fork` like so:

```
[
    ssh,
    -o,
    ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@myjumphost",
    -i,
    ~/.ssh/id_rsa,
    -o,
    StrictHostKeyChecking=no,
    -o,
    PasswordAuthentication=no,
    root@finaldest,
    echo test
]
```

Then run the command like so:

`* karate.fork(args)` where `args` is the array mentioned above

The command works when I paste it into the terminal and run it manually, however when run with `karate.fork` I get

```
zsh:1: no such file or directory: ssh -W finaldest:22 -I ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@myjumphost
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I have tried adding a few backslashes before the `"` in the `ProxyCommand` but no amount of back slashes fixes this issue. I think I am misunderstanding what `karate.fork` is doing to run the command, is there some internal parsing or manipulating of the given input? I was able to get this command to work when I used `useShell: true` however this option breaks other tests for me so I would really like to avoid it.

Comment: without digging much, maybe `echo test` should be on two separate lines ? yes this can be tricky to figure out. refer this answer if you haven't already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62911366/143475 - if all else fails, roll your own utility using java interop

Comment: @Peter Thomas The key was actually to just remove the double quotes in the ProxyCommand option, I guess karate is properly quoting this or doing something behind the scenes

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove the double quotes, seems like they didn't play well with `karate.fork` and the command still runs without them

```
[
    ssh,
    -o,
    ProxyCommand=ssh -W %h:%p -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@myjumphost,
    -i,
    ~/.ssh/id_rsa,
    -o,
    StrictHostKeyChecking=no,
    -o,
    PasswordAuthentication=no,
    root@finaldest,
    echo test
]
```

Comment: nice ! thanks for posting this solution