# Calling shell script file (.sh) using karate feature file

Tags: karate

My shell script file is available under src/test/java/testdata folder.

I tried below code but it did not work.

```
karate.fork({ args: ['cd', 'D:/Users/shr/Desktop/18april/project/src/test/java/data/testdata;', 'bash', 'loadOptions.sh'] })
karate.fork({ args: [ 'bash', 'classpath:testdata/loadOptions.sh'] })
```

Got below error.

> 22:12:12.522 [1686933732519] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - command: [cd, D:/Users/shr/Desktop/18april/project/src/test/java/data/testdata;, bash, loadOptions.sh], working dir: null
>
> 22:12:12.565 [1686933732519] ERROR com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - command error: [cd, D:/Users/shr/Desktop/18april/project/src/test/java/data/testdata;, bash, loadOptions.sh] - Cannot run program "cd": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: keep trying. has to be some path issue. also read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62911366/143475

Comment: Finally, I managed to make it work and below is the working code.

Feature: Executing Shell script Feature

  Background:
    * def command =
"""
function(line,dirPath) {
  karate.exec({ workingDir: dirPath, line: line, useShell: true});
}
"""

  Scenario: Executing Shell script
    * def file = karate.toJavaFile('../features')
    * def path = file.getPath()
    * print "path ",path
    * command('sample.sh',path)