# Accessing kubernetes pod with port-forward to access mongoDb and kafka - error with fork call

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, apache-kafka, karate

Our current mongoDb and kafka setups are on kubernetes pods which requires us to authenticate to the k8 cluster and then port-forward the connection before we can access the mongoDb or kafka applications.

Running in local terminals, we execute the following commands (values modified for security):

```
Terminal 1 (kubeConnection.sh):
  export DEV_DB_PORT=27017
  export DEV_DB_ENDPOINT=db.endpoint
  export DEV_APP_SERVICE_NAME=docdb-access

  kubectl run ${DEV_APP_SERVICE_NAME}  --image=dockerurl/docker/data-platforms/common/socat:latest -it --tty --rm --expose=true --port=${DEV_DB_PORT} tcp-listen:${DEV_DB_PORT},fork,reuseaddr tcp-connect:${DEV_DB_ENDPOINT}:${DEV_DB_PORT}

Terminal 2 (kubePortForward.sh):
  export DEV_DB_PORT=27017
  export DEV_DB_ENDPOINT=db.endpoint
  export DEV_APP_SERVICE_NAME=docdb-access
  kubectl port-forward service/${DEV_APP_SERVICE_NAME} ${DEV_DB_PORT}:${DEV_DB_PORT}
```

Is it possible to use karate.fork to open these 2 terminals?  When trying to setup the first terminal call, we receive an error stating file cannot be found, with or without the arg1 value as [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62910721/how-to-execute-bash-script-using-karate-and-fail-if-script-fails/62911366#62911366):

```
  Scenario: test setup
    * def proc = karate.fork('kubeConnection.sh arg1')
    * proc.waitSync()
    * def procOut = proc.sysOut
    * print ('procOut-',procOut)
    * def procErr = proc.sysErr
    * print ('procErr-',procErr)
    * def procExitCode = proc.exitCode
    * print ('procExitCode-',procExitCode)
    * match procExitCode == 0
```

```
08:53:57.179 [1709049237178] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - command: [kubeConnection.sh, arg1], working dir: null
08:53:57.193 [1709049237178] ERROR com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - command error: [kubeConnection.sh, arg1] - Cannot run program "kubeConnection.sh": error=2, No such file or directory
08:53:57.195 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] null 
08:53:57.196 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] null 
08:53:57.197 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] -1 
08:53:57.205 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] ERROR com.intuit.karate - src/test/java/commonutilhelpers/kubeConnection.feature:36
```

Sample info for kubernetes port-forwarding, if interested - https://komodor.com/learn/kubectl-port-forwarding-how-it-works-use-cases-examples/

Comment: terminals are tricky. yes you may get fork to work, here is an example: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/core/fork-listener.feature - one thought is since kubernetes exposes all kinds of APIs you might get better results calling APIs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/