# Calling an external JS file in Karate

Tags: javascript, karate

I have a JS file with the following code which encypts the request body based on a algorithm:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
function decrypt(key, IV, algorithm, encryptionEncoding, text) {
    try {
        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, IV);
        let decrypted = decipher.update(text, encryptionEncoding);
        return Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]).toString();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};
```

I am calling the same JS file to get the encrypted request body for my feature file to get the encrypted value to pass it as request body using `And request`

```
* def encyptFunc = call read('classpath:encyption.js')
```

I am getting the following error while executing:

```
console.log(decPayload);, <eval>:1:0 Expected an operand but found const
const crypto = require('crypto');
^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 0
  at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.eval(ScriptBindings.java:144)
  at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.updateBindingsAndEval(ScriptBindings.java:134)
  at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.evalInNashorn(ScriptBindings.java:119)
  at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalJsExpression(Script.java:371)
  at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalKarateExpression(Script.java:285)
```

I just want to run this JavaScript file and get the output from it and use the same as the request body.

Can anyone can help with this?

Calling the function using the callonce and read function

Comment: importing or using `require` is not supported. you should be easily able to write the utility in Java (recommended) or JS - or even call JS via the CLI. refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52100077/143475